# Domain Trust Error when calling LsaLookupNames2

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, winapi

I have a asp.net application that is getting

Exception Additional information: The trust relationship between the primary domain and the trusted domain failed.

Which seems to be a catch all for something else that is going on. I actually don't believe that this error has anything to do with Domain Trust Issues but it has to with some other issue. I have started to step through the Microsoft .Net Source with Visual Studio and when calling function

[LsaLookupNames2](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms721798(v=vs.85).aspx) it is returning 3221225868 in the class [NTAccount.cs](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/security/principal/ntaccount.cs,316) on line 316  Does anyone have any idea what else I can do to figure out what is going on ?

I have noticed that this does not happen in **web cassini** but in **IIS Express**

Comment: Is that a C++ or a C# question? If you insist it's both, why and how?

Comment: Some basic reading on ["Windows one hop authentication"](http://www.bing.com/search?q=windows+one+hop+authentication) *may* help. (not really sure if it answers question directly, but at very least it will let you remove most obvious reasons for the error).

Comment: Sorry it's c# I figured some C++ people might know about the function itself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have changed something and these are each things that individually solved my issue. I am going to go with number 2.

1. I found that if I enable the role manager and provide a default
   provider
2. Changing Anonymous Authentication to Disabled (Windows Auth is on)
3. Changing Manged Pipeline to Classic from Integrated

Answer (score 0):

You C# code calls Windows API [LsaLookupNames2](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms721798(v=vs.85).aspx), If the function fails, the return value is one of [NTSTATUS values](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/cc704588.aspx) or one of the LSA Policy Function Return Values.

3221225868 in hex is 0xC000018C, it is NTSTATUS value "STATUS_TRUSTED_DOMAIN_FAILURE", which means: The logon request failed because the trust relationship between the primary domain and the trusted domain failed. That's exact the exception message. You should start with this.

Comment: Ok which matches up with the text error I am getting but I get that error all the time if I can't connect to a local webservice or if the webservices database connection is fown